# Simple DO structure command

Tags: list-manipulation

Excuse the simple question, I have the following structure:

```
 t = {}; Do[f[z_] := Sin[z];
 Sol1 = z f[z];
 AppendTo[t, Re[Sol1]];, {z, -4, 4, 3/4}, {p, {10}}]; t
```

and the result:

```
 {4 Sin[4], 13/4 Sin[13/4], 5/2 Sin[5/2], 7/4 Sin[7/4], Sin[1], 
 1/4 Sin[1/4], 1/2 Sin[1/2], 5/4 Sin[5/4], 2 Sin[2], 11/4 Sin[11/4], 
 7/2 Sin[7/2]}
```

But I need the result as a Grid or in columns and I can't sort the data
as:

```
z     z Sin[z]
-4    4 Sin[z]
-3    -3 Sin[-3]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oops, sorry, typo I didn't notice for 8 minutes, now corrected. How about `t=Table[{z,z*Sin[z]},{z,-4,4,3/4}]` and then `SortBy[t,First]` That should give you two columns and be something you can sort on the first column. For a pretty display `MatrixForm[t]` but you can't do calculations on the pretty form, do the calculations on t

Comment: Generally, it's difficult and clunky to use `Do` and things like `AppendTo`, `For` and `While` in mathematica; usually there's a different and simpler way involving `Table`, `Array`, `Nest`, `Map`, etc.! Bill's solution is an example of a small shift in perspective that might make using mathematica easier and cleaner. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
t = {}; Do[f[z_] := Sin[z];
Sol1 = {z, z f[z]};
AppendTo[t, Re[Sol1]];, {z, -4, 4, 3/4}, {p, {10}}];
PrependTo[t, #] &@{"z", "z f[z]"} // 
Grid[#, Alignment -> {".", 
Automatic, ({1, #} -> Center) & /@ Range[5]}, Frame -> All, 
Spacings -> {1, 1.4}, 
Background -> {None, {Blend[{Cyan, Gray}], {White, Lighter@LightBlue}}}] &
```

[image: Table]

Comment: thanks very much...@E.Chan_Lopez

Answer (score 3):

another option is to use `Sow/Reap` and not use `Append` to build a list.

```
ClearAll[f, z];
f[z_] := Sin[z];
lis = Flatten[First@Rest@Reap@Do[Sow[{z, z f[z]}], {z, -4, 4, 3/4}], 1];
TableForm[lis, TableHeadings -> {None, {z, z Sin[z]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I do not understand what is your `{p, {10}}` is there for. It did nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser but I need the Do command..

Comment: @Charlessilva  The `Do` is still there. I did not remove it.

Comment: Sorry @Nasser I did not see it thanks  anyway..